# Creation of package and import them in another java file

Tags: java, import, package, jmh

I have a folder with structure src/org/openjdk/jmh and in this I have various files such as annotations, generators, infra, profile, results, runner, util.

All these files have various java programs in them .

Now in src/com/user directory I have a benchmark code "JMHSortBenchmark.java" which uses the

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.*;
```

But when I compile the JMHSortBenchmark.java, I get an error as

```
package org.openjdk.jmh.annotations does not exist
package org.openjdk.jmh.runner      does not exist
```

How to get rid of this error or how to create package and import them into the benchmark code?

Or in other words how can I create a package org.openjdk.jmh.annotations and org.openjdk.jmh.runner thereby importing them and use?

Comment: How do you compile your project? Simply with javac? Or do you use maven? Or some kind of IDE? The basic answer is that the dependencies must be on your CLASSPATH both compillation time, and runtime. But it depends on your environment how could you achieve that.

Comment: @Balas Nemes Simply using javac. Actually i used maven but later I just wanted to use javac and test it. So I want to stick with javac!

Comment: Can you please elaborate with respect to the context I provided!

Comment: You can add directories to classpath with the `javac -cp` option. In your case the root for jmh classes is the src directory, so you should try something like: `javac -cp src JMHSortBenchmark.java`

Comment: I did the following "jar cvf src/main/java/lib/incall.jar -C src/main/java/org . "                                                      and then " javac -cp C:/Windows/System32/first-benchmark/src/main/java/lib/incall.jar;. JMHSortBenchmark.java"                                 but still its displaying same error @BalázsNemes

Comment: And what is in the incall.jar now? You can print it with `jar tf <jarfilepath>`

Comment: I tried to push all the javafiles under "org.openjdk.jmh" to incall.jar @BalázsNemes

Comment: There should be class files in the jar not java files. I don't know what is that jmh, but you might be able to download a properly built jmh jar and use it. Or you have to compile your jmh source first. But without the jmh class files on the classpath it won't work.