# ForkedMain Error with Runner in JMH

Tags: java, maven, gradle, microbenchmark, jmh

I've been trying to benchmark a java file. On adding jmh packages and annotations such as @Benchmark, @Mode etc., to test the methods the gradle is working perfectly fine and is generating the measure as well.

But after adding these annotations when I try to execute that java code with simple javac, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The import org.openjdk.jmh.ForkedMain cannot be resolved

    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.<init>(Runner.java:27)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.JMHSortBenchmark.main(JMHSortBenchmark.java:97)
```

There are various self stated solution with pom.xml for the maven projects whereas I am working with gradle.

I am stuck with this error and couldn't debug for long hours. It would really be a great help if someone could help me on this!

Comment: Provide MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But, judging from your previous posts (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965752/creation-of-package-and-import-them-in-another-java-file), you seem to copy JMH sources into the project, and then trying to build? Use the released JMH JAR.